# installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

Tags: devtools

I'm trying to install the package "dev tools" on my machine. I'm using Studio on MacOs. I simply typed

`install.packages("devtools")`, and the installation seems to work, but then I get the error message:   installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status.

I've read a lot of old threads on this already, but they're either for Ubuntu or just not working on my Mac. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Btw, I do have the latest version of Studio installed.

Thanks in advance!